# How to import posts from a csv file to WordPress blog Database

Tags: csv, wordpress

I have a csv file with the following columns

Title | Content | Image | Category

I want to import this csv file to WordPress database. I know a csv file can be imported via phpmyadmin. But when i opened the table 'wp_posts' i couldn't find any columns that says image or category.

Are those in another tables? If so how can i import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHPMyAdmin import isn't recommended. Instead, import via a plugin such as [WP All Import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/).

The reason being is that some data is stored as content in the wp_post table, and some (like category terms) are stored as metacontent in wp_postmeta, with another table describing the relationship.

An import plugin will handle this appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **wp ultimate csv importer** plugin to import & export posts, pages, custom posts and custom fields in to wordpress with the csv files. You can try that plugin and it is cool.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

Answer (score 0):

"Hey there!

For importing CSV files into WordPress, remember that image and category data aren't directly in the 'wp_posts' table. Instead, WordPress stores them in various tables.

If you're not familiar with phpMyAdmin, no problem! Use WordPress's built-in import option under 'Tools' -> 'Import'. Alternatively, try CSV importer plugins like WP Ultimate CSV Importer, which I found easy to use and efficient"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).